# Why it's taking almost 20-30 seconds to change the quality value of the Project Settings... > Quality using script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On a Canvas I have a script attached SettingsMenu :

[image: Settings Menu]

The script that attached to the Canvas :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;

    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _volumeSlider;

    [SerializeField]
    private Dropdown _dropDownQuality;

    public void SetVolume()
    {
        float volume = _volumeSlider.value;
        audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
    }

    public void SetQuality()
    {
        int qualityIndex = _dropDownQuality.value;
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }
}
```

Then on the Graphics (Ui DropDown) on the On Value Changed I'm calling the SetQuality function :

[image: Graphics dropdown setquality]

Then when running the game and the window of the Edit > Project Settings... > Quality is opened when I'm changing in the game the quality it's taking in most of the cases almost 20-30 seconds to change it in the editor Quality window. And it should change it in real time.

It start on Ultra and when I change it to LOW in the game it's taking 20-30 seconds to change it in the editor from Ultra to Low.

[image: Game is running the changes take effect in the editor only after 20-30 seconds]

Comment: It is hard to say, as you did not show us the code of the setting your changed. There can be a ton of work to be executed once this value change. Wich in turn can set of more changes. When you are doing something that might take a long time, it helps a lot if you turn the display off/black/loading screen.

Comment: @Christopher I added the code the SettingsMenu script.

Comment: There is still no definition for `QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel()`, so we still have no idea what it does.

Comment: I found now that it does make the changes fast it's moving the highlight in the Quality window slow but the effect the changes are made in real time in the game. For some reason the game changes and the quality window are not changing the same time but the effect the quality changes do change in real time.

Comment: @Christopher I still don't get it. The QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex); get the quality index and change the quality by the index. I'm calling SetLevel function in the On Value Changed. I don't understand what do you mean by no definition ? I guess I'm missing something in the script ?

Comment: I asumed you did not have the documentation with the "this is expensive work" information. Because that was some custom written function. Turns out it was pre-written and of course had the warning :)

Answer (score 3):

Per [the documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel.html)

> Note that changing the quality level can be an expensive operation if the new level has different anti-aliasing setting. It's fine to change the level when applying in-game quality options, but if you want to dynamically adjustquality level at runtime, pass false to applyExpensiveChanges so that expensive changes are not always applied.

```
QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex, false);
```